# Nodejs App how to call a grpc Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, grpc

I'm trying to figure out how can I call a grpc server from a javascript function in my nodejs application, and update my page... I don't know how can I manage it.

This is the proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package helloworld;

service Greeter {
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
}

message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

this is the server:

```
var PROTO_PATH = __dirname + '/helloworld.proto';

var grpc = require('grpc');
var hello_proto = grpc.load(PROTO_PATH).helloworld;

function sayHello(call, callback) {
    callback(null, {message: 'Hello ' + call.request.name});
}

function main() {
    var server = new grpc.Server();
    server.addProtoService(hello_proto.Greeter.service, {sayHello: sayHello});
    server.bind('0.0.0.0:50051', grpc.ServerCredentials.createInsecure());
    server.start();
}

main();
```

this is the javascript function :

```
var PROTO_PATH = __dirname + '/helloworld.proto';

var grpc = require('grpc');
var hello_proto = grpc.load(PROTO_PATH).helloworld;

function test() {
    var client = new hello_proto.Greeter('localhost:50051',
        grpc.credentials.createInsecure());

    client.sayHello(function(err, response) {
        console.log('Greeting:', response.message);
        document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = 'Mex Received from grpc server ' + response.message;
    });
}
```

when I click a button on my page i call the function test and i would like to update the element(id=para).

Any idea?

Comment: The gRPC library only works with Node.js, on the server side, but you seem to be trying to take actions in the browser. Currently, the best way to do this is to make a regular ajax request to a web server, and have that server translate the request to gRPC and send it to the gRPC server.

Comment: so what i have to do is create a server that is able to translate the request from a browser to a grpc call to another server. Ok I will try to do that. Thank you... i'm new with these technology but i will try to find a way :).